# $wpdb - what does it return on fail?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ezsql

I'm not sure whether this question is WordPress specific or is more related to mySQL.  I am trying to find out what would be returned if the transaction with the database fails.
In the following scenario, I am updating a row.  If none of the values are changed false is returned.  If changes are made true is returned.  How can I tell if the transaction has failed?

```
$result = $wpdb->update($this->table_name, $dbfields, $where);
if($result == false)//do fail - this is not really a fail!
if($result == true)//do success
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Take a look in `wp-includes\wp-db.php`. The header comments of wpdb's update function says:

```
 * @return int|false The number of rows updated, or false on error.
```

So, I'd suspect that you want to find the difference between `false` (a boolean value indicating a failure) and `0` (an integer indicating that no rows were returned.)

If you compare using `==`, `false` and `0` are equal. You therefore need to use the `===` operator to check whether you're dealing with the boolean `false` or the integer `0`.

So, try these:

```
if ($result === false) // Fail -- the "===" operator compares type as well as value
if ($result === 0) // Success, but no rows were updated
if ($result > 0) // Success, and updates were done. $result is the number of affected rows.
```

See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information on the === comparison operator.

Comment: Is there a way we could get more information about the cause of failure, error description?

Comment: @Bearwithit Try checking `$wpdb->last_error`. That's a public (string) variable that should have a description of the last error.

Comment: Thank you so much!